# Can I Connect Apache Derby DataBase with Android Application?

Tags: java, android, database-connection, derby

I'm preparing an Android Application related to restaurant management. I need to connect the application in another windows application like pos software. That windows application uses Apache Derby database. Can I connect that windows pos with front end of my android App?

Answer (score 6):

You can't connect to the derby database directly from android using the derby client jdbc drivers since derby doesn't support android, see [DERBY-4458](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-4458) for details.

The best way of doing this would be to modify the windows POS to expose a rest interface, and have you android app talk to the POS through REST.

If you can't modify the POS app, and if derby is running in [client server](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/getstart/cgsquck13780.html) mode on the POS app, you could write another java app that ran on the same machine which talked to derby using [jdbc](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/getstart/rgsquck30197.html), and have that new java app expose a REST interface.

Comment: can you suggest me any web links or book for the REST interface? Actually im new to it and a good advise can lead me to good start.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this if your problem is still not solved: [Awake SQL](http://www.awake-sql.org)  Proves to be good solution on this. I am trying it myself to see if it works or not.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - `You don't have permission to access /
on this server. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`